# YouCompleteMe Library Recognition

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, youcompleteme

I recently installed the C++ [YouCompleteMe](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%2B%2BYouCompleteMe) package for [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). I followed the guide on the first link and found that YouCompleteMe completes C-based expression, like easily getting the for-loop structure done for you when typing *for* etc.

What I want, however, is functionality that completes my calls to installed library functions. So, for example, I have installed the Automatak [opendnp3](https://github.com/automatak/dnp3) libraries and included them in my source. Now when I use a opendnp3 method, say I declare an object:

```
DNP3Manager manager;
```

And then want to easily access DNP3Manager functions:

```
manager.someFunction();
```

When I get to the '.' I want a drop-down menu listing all the possibilities. I thought that is what YouCompleteMe does, or am I wrong?

I've also come across a **.ycm_custom_config.py** file that one can create within a project directory. This file only seems to specify flags for compilation though, and when I create it, the functionality is still not achieved.

How can I get that completion functionality in Sublime Text?

Comment: If you're having a problem with a particular package, the best thing to do would be to first contact the author by filing an [issue](https://github.com/glymehrvrd/CppYCM/issues) on Github.

Comment: thanks I have done so. StackOverflow may be a faster way of doing it though, considering probably only one person checks his issues page while overflow may have many sublime users.